# I can't connect MySQL VPS with SSH tunnel with Workbench

Tags: ssh, mysql-workbench, ssh-tunnel

I've installed MySQL on my VPS server. Via MySQL Workbench, I was able to connect to the MySQL server on my VPS to create a database with tables.
However, as my IP address is dynamic, MySQL Workbench no longer connects me, and to solve this problem while connecting securely, I opted for the SSH tunnel solution.
As I understand it, in my Mac's Terminal, the following command creates an SSH tunnel and redirects traffic to port 3307 on my computer: 
`ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 user@IPadressVPS -N`

In my VPS **MySQL server configuration file** (sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf) I have this:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

As for port opening rules, UFW allows the following (sudo ufw status):

```
o Action of
-- ------ ----
22/tcp ALLOW Anywhere                  
80/tcp Allowed anywhere                  
443 Allowed anywhere                  
8433:8443/tcp Allowed anywhere                  
3306 Allowed anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6) Allowed anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6) Allowed anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6) Allowed everywhere (v6)             
8433:8443/tcp (v6) Allowed everywhere (v6)             
3306 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
```

In my terminal, when I type the command ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 user@IPadressVPS -N I'm asked for my password, which I enter, and then nothing happens (I don't know if this is normal).
Then from MySQLWorkbench, I enter the following information (see screenshot):
SSH Hostname: 127.0.0.1
SSH Username: root
SSH Password: the password 
SSH Key File: (I don't put anything)
MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQL Server Port: 3307
Username: root (MySQL root user)
Password: MySQL root password
Default Schema: (I don't put anything)

When I click on "Test Connection", I get an error message:

> **Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3307 through SSH tunnel at root@127.0.0.1  with user root**
> Cannot open SSH Tunnel: Connection refused

How can I solve this problem?

[image: impossible to connect via SSL tunnel]